# Bind several classes into one .dll file in C#

Tags: c#, dll

A beginner's question. It is c#.
Let's say I have three classes in one project named Employee, Department, Address. For some reason, I would like to have a .dll file (let's name it test.dll) to have all three classes included that I can call it from some other project using syntax like "test.Employee emp1 = new test.Employee();"
That is my idea. Is this possible? If yes, how should I do that? Do I have to create a class library project to do so? I know nothing about a class library project. So I may need further help with that. 
If the answer is no, how do I add references to those classes from other solutions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a class library project.
2. Give it a proper namespace
3. Write your library classes, then compile to a dll
4. Then add a reference to that dll in the other project you want to use it in
5. add a `using` statement to include the reference in your code files.

Pretty straightforward

Comment: Ummm, well you create some code files in your project then perform a build action. The dll will be usually output to a bin directory in the project directory.

Comment: Well.. Great thanks to the answer. Now I have the dll file. However, after I add reference to the dll file from the other solution, I cannot "using" it, as VS says that the type or namespace could not be found.. I've already add the reference and it shows up in the reference list. Why can't I use it?

Comment: You have to use the namespace that you put the class files into. Something to the effect of ... `using MyNamespaceInsideMyDll;`

Comment: I have set both side to the same namespace, but still not working.

Comment: I have that in a different solution. Does that matter?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter. You just need to make sure you have a reference added to the library and then you should be able to detect the namespace when doing the using clause